# Пример вывод в консоль из книги Шилдта

Tags: c#

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num;
        int nextdigit;
        int numdigits;
        int[] n = new int[20];
        string[] digits = { "нуль", "один", "два", 
                            "три", "четыре", "пять", 
                            "шесть", "семь", "восемь", 
                                            "девять" };
        num = 1908;
        Console.WriteLine("Число: " + num);
        Console.Write("Число словами: ");
        nextdigit = 0;
        numdigits = 0;
        // Получить отдельные цифры и сохранить их в массиве п. 
        // Эти цифры сохраняются в обратном порядке, 
        do
        {
            nextdigit = num % 10;
            n[numdigits] = nextdigit;
            numdigits++;
            num = num / 10;
        } while (num > 0);
        numdigits--;
        // Вывести полученные слова. 
        for (; numdigits >= 0; numdigits--)
            Console.Write(digits[n[numdigits]] + " ");
        Console.WriteLine(); 
    }
```

Разъясните, пожалуйста, как можно проще.

1. Каким образом тут целое число преобразуется в слова?
2. Зачем тут numdigits-- никак не могу понять?
3. Как работает цикл for?

Comment: Умение понимать что происходит в коде - основное умение:) Я читал и понимал непонятный код так: брал листочек с ручкой и прямо словами записывал, построчно, что происходит в коде. "Создаем переменную такую", "Создаем массив такой", "Пишем в консоль такой-то текст", "наша переменная теперь == 0", "начинаем цикл, начальные данные такие", "в этой итерации цикла сделали вот это", "начали следующую итерацию цикла" и так далее. Помогает здорово. SO это хорошо, но понять и разобрать учебную литературу вы должны сами

Comment: спасибо, господа, с отладчиком я во всем разобрался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте медленно и вдумчиво оттрассировать программу *вручную* или (лучше!) с отладчиком. Что у вас будет в массиве `n`?

> Десятичные цифры исходного числа 1908.

Теперь, если например `numdigits` равно 0, чему равно `n[numdigits]`? А чему равно тогда `digits[n[numdigits]]`?

Как только вы ответите на эти вопросы, логика кода станет вам понятна.

---

Я намеренно не отвечаю на вопрос слишком подробно: разбор кода с отладчиком — очень нужное умение, которое можно приобрести только на личном опыте.